# React redux multiple calls to the same action triggers reducer only once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my current react application I am using redux for state management. I have a Like Feed Post action. If I trigger the action 2 times with different parameters it will only return a single success action.
i.e. If I like 2 different posts very fast, the request action is called twice, but the success action only once. So in the reducer I will only get the change from a single like.
The action

```
export const likeFeedPostAsync = createAsyncAction(
  'LIKE_FEED_POST_REQUEST',
  'LIKE_FEED_POST_SUCCESS',
  'LIKE_FEED_POST_FAILURE',
  'LIKE_FEED_POST_IDLE',
)<
  { id: number; bearer: string; entityId: number; type: CommentType },
  { id: number; entityId: number; type: CommentType },
  string,
  null
>();
```

This is from the redux dev tools

[image]

I want to get a success action for each request action. So I can change the state correctly.

The epic function that dispatches the `likeFeedPostAsync.success`

```
export const likeFeedPostEpic: EpicFunction = (action$, state$, { api }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(likeFeedPostAsync.request)),
    switchMap(action =>
      from(
        api.feed.likeFeedPost(action.payload.id, action.payload.bearer, action.payload.entityId, action.payload.type),
      ).pipe(
        map(likeFeedPostAsync.success),
        catchError(error => handleError(error, likeFeedPostAsync)),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox?

Comment: I guess in the code that dispatches `likeFeedPostAsync.success` you have some errors but since that code is not in your question I don't think anyone can answer your question.